# Android Turn on the screen and start an activity when it's off

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-wake-lock

I am making an alarm app and I'm at the stage where I need to display the alarm screen (AlarmActivity) as onReceive from BroadcastReceiver is called.
Here are the things I need to achieve when it's time for alarm to ring.

1. When the screen is off, turn on the device and display the alarm screen when it's time.
2. When the screen is on but the app is off, display the alarm screen.
3. When the screen is on and the user is in the alarm app, display the alarm screen.

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work.
[Start activity even when screen is turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336946/start-activity-even-when-screen-is-turned-off)

onCreate of my main activity is..

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        myIntent1.putExtra("msg", "Wake up Wake up1");
        myIntent1.putExtra("repeat", 0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2571123, myIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
```

It sets the alarm on certain time.

This is my AlarmReceiver class.

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        Log.d("ALARMONMATE",msg);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmActivity.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent1.putExtra("msg",msg);
        context.startActivity(intent1);
```

Here is my AlarmActivity.java, the screen I want to display on alarm call.

```
public class SampleAlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wake = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_alarm);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        txt.setText(msg);






        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wake = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "App:wakeuptag");
        wake.acquire(1*60*1000);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
        } else {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could at least leave a link that I can refer to or concepts that would be helpful in this case, that would be great.
I've looked into WakeLock and well over 20 questions about this issue. However, I wasn't too sure if they were outdated or not as majority of them are from over 8 years ago.

Comment: You cannot start activities from the background on recent versions of Android. You should be able to use a high-priority `Notification` with a full-screen `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare 
According to description from https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts. It says there are exceptions to the restriction. One of them states

"The app receives a notification PendingIntent from the system. In the case of pending intents for services and broadcast receivers, the app can start activities for a few seconds after the pending intent is sent."

I'm using pending intent to trigger the alarm so I wonder if that couldn't be the exception explained in the page.

Comment: You are not using a `Notification`. "A notification `PendingIntent`" refers to a `PendingIntent` triggered by a user's interaction with a `Notification`.

Comment: @CommonsWare That makes sense thank you. That leaves a question though. How do alarm apps out there show a full screen when the alarm goes on with so many restrictions?

Comment: AFAIK, they use a high-priority `Notification` with a full-screen `Intent`. With my device's screen on, I get a "heads-up" popup about the alarm. With my device's screen off, I get the activity identified by the full-screen `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you so much for sparing your time. I'll look into it ASAP.